# What should [results] be used for?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I just noticed that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3552932/mleko) removes the `[results]` tag from a lot of questions and I have no idea whether I should accept or reject such edits.
For which questions is this tag approriate? Results is a broad term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/results) is definitely too broad. It needs to be removed either by burnination or manual editing.

Community vote against [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/result) can be viewed on MSE at: [Burninate [result]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183705/burninate-result)